# Sitecore Command Locking Up Entire Web Server

Tags: coveo

So I have an issue, not sure what to do

I have a standard Sitecore command, that is running about a 15 minutes process

It is crawling a restful API and sticking documents into  Coveo Push source, seems to be working fine

But for some reason, even though the code is using multi-threading (HttpClient.PostAsAsync etc) it locks up the entire web server while the process is running

Does anybody have any ideas here?

I look at the proper indexing page, and it does not do that, So there must be a way

Thanks much
Baxter

Comment: By "locks up" do you mean that code just stops while this executes, or that the server resources are so high that it stops responding?

Comment: The command runs just fine, but I can do nothing else on that instance of Sitecore while it runs.